# How to use actual window size to control vim settings?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, neovim, plugin-tagbar

Background: neovim with [tagbar plugin](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar) installed

Goal: when starting nvim, if current window size is larger than 100, open tagbar and set auto-open for new buffers.

Currently I use the settings below to achieve auto-open for supported files in new buffers:

```
autocmd VimEnter * nested :call tagbar#autoopen(1)
```

I want the auto-open be controlled by window width because sometimes I use a narrow terminal split by iTerms or tmux, tagbar is not suitable to open in this situation.

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
" if I add `echo winwidth('%') here, it will show 80, not the current terminal width
if winwidth('%') > 100
    autocmd VimEnter * nested :call tagbar#autoopen(1)
endif
```

It seems that `winwidth('%')` returns number of `columns` when nvimrc is executed (I didn't overwrite columns, the default value is 80), so the `if` is always false and the tagbar never auto-opens. But when I execute `:echo winwidth('%')` after nvim is opened, the result is 154, represents the actual width of current terminal window.

Please help me find out the right `if` statement, or gives another solution lead to the same goal.

Comment: Move the code to `after/plugin/an_arbitrary_name.vim`. Or, alternatively, you can move `if / endif` into the auto command.

Comment: @muru Not sure if I'm misreading either, but isn't your question about determining the size in pixels of the window, and this question about getting the *correct* size (in characters) during startup?

Comment: @Rich ah, yes. I'll retract my vote.

Comment: @Rich Sorry for the vague description, I've updated the title and some of the content, hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the hint, will try.